# Support needed for a query

Tags: mysql, sql, woocommerce

I need help to finish a SQL Query for a Woocommerce product list. I need this for a wpdatatable sql input.

I searched for a example code and have adapted a found code:

```
SELECT
  p.ID,
  p.post_title,
  p.post_content,
  p.post_excerpt,
  t.name AS product_category,
  t.term_id AS product_id,
  tt.term_taxonomy_id AS tt_term_taxonomia,
  tr.term_taxonomy_id AS tr_term_taxonomia,
  MAX(CASE WHEN pm1.meta_key = '_price' then pm1.meta_value ELSE NULL END) as price
FROM wp_posts p 
LEFT JOIN wp_postmeta pm1 ON pm1.post_id = p.ID
LEFT JOIN wp_term_relationships AS tr ON tr.object_id = p.ID
JOIN wp_term_taxonomy AS tt ON tt.taxonomy = 'product_cat' AND tt.term_taxonomy_id = tr.term_taxonomy_id 
JOIN wp_terms AS t ON t.term_id = tt.term_id
WHERE p.post_type in('product', 'product_variation') AND p.post_status = 'publish'
GROUP BY p.ID,p.post_title
```

It works but without product rows for variable products. It shows only the main variation of a product.

Example: 
product steak: I have 6 different variations of steaks as own products with different prices and also different weight characteristics.
With my SQL query I can only see the main product "steak" without variations and variation prices.

**Table wp_Posts**

```
id   | post_title                     | post_type         | post_parent | post_name | regular_price |
-----+--------------------------------+-------------------+-------------+-----------+---------------|
4113 | Steaks                         | product           | 0           |
4119 | Steaks-Lungenbraten Steak 125g | product_variation | 4113        | steaks_4  |6              |
4120 | Steaks-Hüftsteak 200g          | product_variation | 4113        | steaks_5  |4,4            |
4121 | Steaks-Flankensteak 600g       | product_variation | 4113        | steaks_6  |8,4            |
```

**Table wp_postmeta-**

```
Post_ID |meta_key                | meta_value         |
--------+----------------+----------------------------+---------
4113    |                        | 
4119    | attribute_pa_steaks    | lungenbraten-steak |
4119    | _price.                | 6                  |
4120    | attribute_pa_steaks    | hueftsteak         |
4120    | _price.                | 4,4                |
4121    | attribute_pa_steaks    | flanksteak         |
4121    | _price.                | 8,4                |
```

**wp_term_relationship**

```
object_id.  | term_taxonomy_id. | term_order |
------------+-------------------+------------+
4113        |    6              |    0       |
4113        |   296             |    0       |
4113        |   297             |    0       |
4113        |   298             |    0       |
```

**wp_term_taxonomy**

```
term_taxonomy_id. | term_id  | taxonomy    | description. | parent |count |
------------------+----------+-------------+--------------+--------+------+
296               |   296    |  pa_steaks  |              |  0     | 1.   |
297               |   297    |  pa_steaks  |              |  0     | 1.   |
298               |   298    |  pa_steaks  |              |  0     | 1.   |
```

**wp_terms**

```
term_id     |  name              | slug               | term_group | 
------------+--------------------+--------------------+------------+
296         | Flanksteak         | flanksteak         | 0          |
297         | Hüftsteakk         | hueftsteak         | 0          |
298         | Lungenbraten Steak | Lungenbraten-steak | 0          |
```

**[image: Result of query]**

Comment: You typically GROUP BY the same columns as you SELECT, except those who are arguments to set functions.

Comment: Show us some sample table data and the expected result - as formatted text, not images. And take a look at [mcve] before you start.

Comment: Example:

woo variable product: 

                                   Name              Price

                                    Steak
variation 1:                  Flank steak      8,4
variation 2:                  Hüftsteak.        4,4
Variation 3:                 Lungenbraten   6,0




Result SQL Query as is:

                                    Steak                8,4

Comment: As to jarlh's comment on `GROUP BY`: You group by post, so as to get one result row per post. But a post can have many terms, how then can you select *the* term with the post. We'd expect that you either group by term, too, so as to get one result row per post and term, or only select aggregates from the terms, e.g. the maximum term_id and the minimum term_taxonomy_id.

Comment: As to sample data: Please edit your request to show it. Show an example with data per table. For your three steak variants: what is in table `posts`? What is in table `wp_postmeta`? What is in table `terms`...

Comment: As mentioned: Edit your request. Below your request there is the word `edit`. Click it and you can add your sample data into the request.

Comment: And what if you change all the `INNER JOIN` to `LEFT JOIN`?

Comment: @ LukStorms: Thank you very much, this was really my mistake. Now it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your query is invalid, as the select list doesn't match the `GROUP BY`. Even if you DBMS is flawed and doesn't raise an error, I don't recommend using such a query. It's results may be arbitrary (as is the case in MySQL for instance). Write a query that leaves no doubt as to what data you really want to select.

As you want just one value from the key/value table `wp_postmeta`, you don't need aggregation:

```
SELECT
  p.id,
  p.post_title,
  p.post_content,
  p.post_excerpt,
  t.name AS product_category,
  t.term_id AS product_id,
  tt.term_taxonomy_id AS tt_term_taxonomia,
  tr.term_taxonomy_id AS tr_term_taxonomia,
  pm1.meta_value AS price
FROM wp_posts p 
LEFT JOIN wp_postmeta pm1 ON pm1.post_id = p.ID AND pm1.meta_key = '_price'
JOIN wp_term_relationships AS tr ON tr.object_id = p.ID
JOIN wp_term_taxonomy AS tt ON tt.taxonomy = 'product_cat'
                           AND tt.term_taxonomy_id = tr.term_taxonomy_id 
JOIN wp_terms AS t ON t.term_id = tt.term_id
WHERE p.post_type in('product', 'product_variation') AND p.post_status = 'publish'
ORDER BY
  CASE WHEN p.post_parent = 0 THEN id else post_parent END,
  CASE WHEN p.post_parent = 0 THEN 1 else 2 END;
```

Comment: Thank you very much, it works, the table shows all rows with the correct price but  in the column post_title only the text of the post_parent 4104. How can I get the correct post_titles for this rows?

Comment: 4104 doesn't mean anything to me. You haven't shown the tables `wp_term_relationships` and `wp_term_taxonomy` in your example. Maybe there are posts without terms and you still want to show them? Then you must turn all joins to left outer joins. Apart from this:The query shows the posts' titles stored in the posts' rows shown. Is this not what you want?

Comment: Sorry, I was to late for adapting the text. I mean 4113. The right post_title for the post_type product_variation are also in the wp_posts.
(I am new in your forum and therefore I have to learn a lot how to use comment ...).

Comment: The query selects p.id, p.post_title, p_post_content, etc. They are read directly from the table `wp_posts`. So for ID 4113 you must see 'Steaks' and for ID 4119 you must see 'Steaks-Lungenbraten Steak 125g'. You are saying that you see ID 4113 with 'Steaks-Lungenbraten Steak 125g'? This is impossible from the data you have shown. So, either your data is not what you think it is or you are using some tool that mixes row data somehow. That latter is highly unlikely, so please examine your table data.

Comment: I have add a picture of the query result in the question part. You can see that the price of the product_variations is correct but the id and the post_title shows always the parent data and don't change for the product_variations.

Comment: It doesn't look like the product variations are shown at all. Instead it seems only the products are taken from the `wm_posts` table and then shown multifold, because they get somehow mixed up with variant data. I surmise that something on the way from `wp_posts` to `wp_terms` is wrong. Please edit your request again and show what the tables `wp_term_relationships` and `wp_term_taxonomy` contain. Or just look at the data and retrace the way through the joins yourself to understand what's happening.

Comment: I corrected also the data of the tables shown in the question above.

Comment: But you are still not showing the tables `wp_term_relationships` and `wp_term_taxonomy`. Obviously the tables must be joined differently from what you have shown in your query. But I cannot know how. I don't know the tables. I don't know what they contain. As mentioned. Just look at the tables. Look at the rows. Look at the joins. You can write it on paper what rows are joined and thus probably spot the error. If you fail to do so, then show us your table data so we can help. You can even create a fiddle, so we can play with your data: https://dbfiddle.uk/

Comment: I have tried to show the missing tables in my question above. I am not really firm in SQL and therefore I need really help. Sorry, if I gave you not the correct informations. If you like, I could give you an access to the db. Best greetings from Salzburg.

Comment: I have problems understanding this database. It's obvious though, that joining on `wp_term_relationships.object_id = wp_posts.id` has no match, except for the product itself. The join removes all product variations from the query. One could outer join on `wp_posts.post_parent` instead and then maybe try to match `wp_terms.slug = wp_postmeta.meta_value`, but this may just as well be completely wrong. I don't know how the tables are supposed to be related. You may have better luck asking a question on WordPress table relations in a WordPress forum or here, or read some docs on this.